# Reddit text field implementation Material-UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

So I'm trying to immitate the reddit text field implementation from material-ui, I've gone ahead and setup this custom component, but I'm getting a **invalid hook call** error everytime I run on the `const classes=...` Line

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { fade, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import styles from "./LNTextField.module.css";

const useStylesReddit = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    border: "1px solid #e2e2e1",
    overflow: "hidden",
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: "#fcfcfb",
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["border-color", "box-shadow"]),
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#fff"
    },
    "&$focused": {
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      boxShadow: `${fade(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.25)} 0 0 0 2px`,
      borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main
    }
  },
  focused: {}
}));

class LNTextField extends Component {
  render() {
    var classNames = require("classnames");
    const classes = useStylesReddit();

    return (
      <TextField
        InputProps={{ classes, disableUnderline: true }}
        {...this.props}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default LNTextField;
```

Also since I just copied it I'm not sure how I can type this code in a seperate css files and refer to the hover and focused bits appropriately, so If you could also tell me how to do that that'd be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to React, you are getting this error because:

> You can’t use Hooks inside of a class component

Convert your class component to functional component:

```
const LNTextField = props => {
    var classNames = require("classnames");
    const classes = useStylesReddit();

    return (
      <TextField
        InputProps={{ classes, disableUnderline: true }}
        {...props}
      />
    );
}
```